# How to update <select> options in my case?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors, jquery-events

I have a select field and a button:

```
<select id="mylist"></select>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="update">
```

my js code:

```
var btn=$('#btn');
btn.click(function(){
   var optionList = GET_LIST();// GET_LIST() returns a array of strings which is the option texts.

   //How to use optionList to update the options in <select> ?
});
```

How to update my options list with `optionList` in select tag ?

Comment: It returns a array of strings which is the options text

Comment: What do you mean "update" the options? You want to update them how?

Comment: @Ryan, means the <select> options are updated based on the content of optionList

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: Based on note from @amsutil alternate using html:

```
var btn=$('#btn');
btn.click(function(){
     var optionList = GET_LIST();
     var select  = $("#mylist");
     select.html("");
     var optionsHTML = "";
     $.each(optionList, function(a, b){
        optionsHTML += "<option>" + b + "</option>";
     });
     select.html(optionsHTML);
});
```

Try this:

```
var btn=$('#btn');
btn.click(function(){
     var optionList = GET_LIST();
     var select  = $("#mylist");
      select.empty();
     $.each(optionList, function(a, b){
        select.append("<option>" + b + "</option>");
     });
});
```

Comment: If you're going to press this button more than once you might want to remove the children (options) from the select first?

Comment: @Chris: Updated the post to handle the issue you mentioned.

Comment: I wouldn't use append. For one it creates too many DOM manipulations (imagine if you had 200 elements in this array, like a country list) and also you have to keep on emptying it every time. If you store all the new options as a string, and use .html() to add it to the select, both this issues are eradicated.

Comment: But this will keep the previous list of options if there is a new update...how to remove the previous optionlist?

Answer (score 0):

Using `$.map()` to convert an array of strings into an array of option elements:

```
var optionList = GET_LIST();
var options = $.map(optionList, function (item, i) {
    return $('<option>', {text: item});   // Convert string into <option>
});
$('#mylist').empty().append(options);     // Append to the <select>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to create select options from an array, your values and label text will match. These will need to be stored in an object if you want to have values and text be different:

```
var btn = $('#btn');

btn.click(function() {
    var optionList = GET_LIST();
    var element = $('#mylist');

    $.each(optionList, function(index, value) {
       element.append('<option value="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>');
    });
});
```

Comment: But this will keep the previous list of options if there is a new update...how to remove the previous optionlist?

Answer (score 0):

I see a few answers using 'append', but this creates too many DOM manipulations. If you have a large number of values in your array, it could slow the site down. It's much better to store all of the new options in a string, and do one DOM manipulation at the end.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/ubotu4/